# Java AES - message digest for the key

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I recently searched for Java code to encrypt data with AES and found this piece of code on the net:

```
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update(getSecretKey().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        // Then encrypt
        byte[] iv = initIV();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(encoding));
```

I'd like to understand why the developer used a MessageDigest with the secret key. What are the benefits of such an approach, instead of writing:

```
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(getSecretKey().getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        // Then encrypt
        byte[] iv = initIV();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(encoding));
```

Many thanks in advance

Gilles

Answer (score 1):

By taking the SHA-256 hash of `getSecretKey().getBytes("UTF-8")` you are guaranteed to get a 256-bit AES key no matter the size of the String returned by `getSecretKey()`. This is a useful property. The programmer is essentially using SHA-256 as an ad-hoc [key derivation function](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2)(KDF). However, there are carefully designed KDFs designed by cryptographers that are better choices. For example, if the value returned by `getSecretKey()` is a password or something like a password then a password hashing algorithm like [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2), [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), or [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The significant difference is, that in the above code a hash (SHA-256) of `getSecretKey()` is applied to construct the AES-key.

In the below code `getSecretKey()` is taken raw/applied directly.

...the above i would consider as "more secure";)